# Order legend according to the color sequence in geom_area

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a stack plot for a data of 3 years, using `geom_area`. It is working perfectly fine, except that I would like the legend order as per the color sequence. I am mentioning the sample data and code below:

```
#sample dataset
df <- structure(list(
  Topic = c("Topic_A", "Topic_A", "Topic_A", "Topic_A", "Topic_A", "Topic_A", "Topic_A", "Topic_A", "Topic_A", "Topic_A", "Topic_A", "Topic_A", "Topic_B", "Topic_B", "Topic_B", "Topic_B", "Topic_B", "Topic_B", "Topic_B", "Topic_B", "Topic_B", "Topic_B", "Topic_B", "Topic_B", "Topic_C", "Topic_C", "Topic_C", "Topic_C", "Topic_C", "Topic_C", "Topic_C", "Topic_C", "Topic_C", "Topic_C", "Topic_C", "Topic_D", "Topic_D", "Topic_D", "Topic_D", "Topic_D", "Topic_D", "Topic_D", "Topic_D", "Topic_D", "Topic_D", "Topic_D", "Topic_E", "Topic_E", "Topic_E", "Topic_E", "Topic_E", "Topic_E", "Topic_E", "Topic_E", "Topic_E", "Topic_E", "Topic_E", "Topic_E", "Topic_F", "Topic_F", "Topic_F", "Topic_F", "Topic_F", "Topic_F", "Topic_F", "Topic_F", "Topic_F", "Topic_F", "Topic_F", "Topic_G", "Topic_G", "Topic_G", "Topic_G", "Topic_G", "Topic_G", "Topic_G", "Topic_G", "Topic_G", "Topic_G", "Topic_G", "Topic_G", "Topic_H", "Topic_H", "Topic_H", "Topic_H", "Topic_H", "Topic_H", "Topic_H", "Topic_H", "Topic_H", "Topic_H", "Topic_H", "Topic_H", "Topic_I", "Topic_I", "Topic_I", "Topic_I", "Topic_I", "Topic_I", "Topic_I"), Frequency = c(22L, 27L, 68L, 34L, 60L, 13L, 23L, 11L, 12L, 23L, 19L, 22L, 9L, 36L, 127L, 83L, 37L, 19L, 31L, 19L, 32L, 25L, 20L, 17L, 19L, 22L, 48L, 32L, 36L, 71L, 37L, 12L, 10L, 37L, 48L, 11L, 15L, 10L, 9L, 19L, 19L, 14L, 22L, 51L, 14L, 33L, 22L, 36L, 16L, 10L, 31L, 36L, 15L, 10L, 20L, 23L, 21L, 14L, 20L, 17L, 18L, 22L, 9L, 14L, 37L, 18L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 47L, 28L, 34L, 68L, 227L, 22L, 25L, 8L, 11L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 34L, 8L, 21L, 4L, 5L, 33L, 19L, 12L, 18L, 22L, 23L, 38L, 96L, 112L, 53L, 87L, 103L, 58L, 44L),
  Timestamp = structure(c(17897, 17928, 17957, 17988, 18018, 18048, 18079, 18109, 18169, 18200, 18230, 18233, 18262, 18302, 18323, 18353, 18383, 18414, 18444, 18475, 18535, 18566, 18596, 18599, 18628, 18660, 18713, 18744, 18770, 18799, 18827, 18856, 18884, 18913, 18944, 18628, 18660, 18713, 18744, 18770, 18799, 18827, 18856, 18884, 18913, 18944, 18262, 18302, 18323, 18353, 18383, 18414, 18444, 18475, 18535, 18566, 18596, 18599, 18628, 18660, 18713, 18744, 18770, 18799, 18827, 18856, 18884, 18913, 18944, 17897, 17928, 17957, 17988, 18018, 18048, 18079, 18109, 18169, 18200, 18230, 18233, 18262, 18302, 18323, 18353, 18383, 18414, 18444, 18475, 18535, 18566, 18596, 18599, 17897, 17928, 17957, 17988, 18018, 18048, 18079), class = "Date")
), row.names = c(5L, 10L, 15L, 20L, 25L, 30L, 35L, 40L, 45L, 50L, 55L, 60L, 61L, 66L, 71L, 76L, 81L, 86L, 91L, 96L, 101L, 106L, 111L, 116L, 122L, 127L, 132L, 137L, 142L, 147L, 152L, 157L, 162L, 167L, 172L, 124L, 129L, 134L, 139L, 144L, 149L, 154L, 159L, 164L, 169L, 174L, 62L, 67L, 72L, 77L, 82L, 87L, 92L, 97L, 102L, 107L, 112L, 117L, 125L, 130L, 135L, 140L, 145L, 150L, 155L, 160L, 165L, 170L, 175L, 3L, 8L, 13L, 18L, 23L, 28L, 33L, 38L, 43L, 48L, 53L, 58L, 63L, 68L, 73L, 78L, 83L, 88L, 93L, 98L, 103L, 108L, 113L, 118L, 1L, 6L, 11L, 16L, 21L, 26L, 31L), class = "data.frame")
```

Below is the simple code I am using to produce the plot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Timestamp, y=Frequency, fill=Topic)) + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = '1 month', date_labels = "%b-%y")+
  geom_area(alpha=0.6 , size=1, colour="black", position = position_fill())+
  scale_fill_discrete(guide = guide_legend()) + #, breaks = df_q$Topic #to sort legends
  theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.box = "horizontal")+
  ggtitle("Questionable")+
  xlab("Month")+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 1))
```

I am getting the following output:
[image]

Is it possible to order the legend (ignoring **Topic** order) as per the sequence of color from left(2019) to right(2021) and top to bottom? For instance, orange (top color in 2019) should be first one in legend, blue second and so on. And it would be really great to know if there's a way each legend just below its corresponding year, to easily differntiate the topic for each year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify the order manually with the limits argument to `scale_fill`

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- structure(list(
  Topic = c("Topic_A", "Topic_A", "Topic_A", "Topic_A", "Topic_A", "Topic_A", "Topic_A", "Topic_A", "Topic_A", "Topic_A", "Topic_A", "Topic_A", "Topic_B", "Topic_B", "Topic_B", "Topic_B", "Topic_B", "Topic_B", "Topic_B", "Topic_B", "Topic_B", "Topic_B", "Topic_B", "Topic_B", "Topic_C", "Topic_C", "Topic_C", "Topic_C", "Topic_C", "Topic_C", "Topic_C", "Topic_C", "Topic_C", "Topic_C", "Topic_C", "Topic_D", "Topic_D", "Topic_D", "Topic_D", "Topic_D", "Topic_D", "Topic_D", "Topic_D", "Topic_D", "Topic_D", "Topic_D", "Topic_E", "Topic_E", "Topic_E", "Topic_E", "Topic_E", "Topic_E", "Topic_E", "Topic_E", "Topic_E", "Topic_E", "Topic_E", "Topic_E", "Topic_F", "Topic_F", "Topic_F", "Topic_F", "Topic_F", "Topic_F", "Topic_F", "Topic_F", "Topic_F", "Topic_F", "Topic_F", "Topic_G", "Topic_G", "Topic_G", "Topic_G", "Topic_G", "Topic_G", "Topic_G", "Topic_G", "Topic_G", "Topic_G", "Topic_G", "Topic_G", "Topic_H", "Topic_H", "Topic_H", "Topic_H", "Topic_H", "Topic_H", "Topic_H", "Topic_H", "Topic_H", "Topic_H", "Topic_H", "Topic_H", "Topic_I", "Topic_I", "Topic_I", "Topic_I", "Topic_I", "Topic_I", "Topic_I"), Frequency = c(22L, 27L, 68L, 34L, 60L, 13L, 23L, 11L, 12L, 23L, 19L, 22L, 9L, 36L, 127L, 83L, 37L, 19L, 31L, 19L, 32L, 25L, 20L, 17L, 19L, 22L, 48L, 32L, 36L, 71L, 37L, 12L, 10L, 37L, 48L, 11L, 15L, 10L, 9L, 19L, 19L, 14L, 22L, 51L, 14L, 33L, 22L, 36L, 16L, 10L, 31L, 36L, 15L, 10L, 20L, 23L, 21L, 14L, 20L, 17L, 18L, 22L, 9L, 14L, 37L, 18L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 47L, 28L, 34L, 68L, 227L, 22L, 25L, 8L, 11L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 34L, 8L, 21L, 4L, 5L, 33L, 19L, 12L, 18L, 22L, 23L, 38L, 96L, 112L, 53L, 87L, 103L, 58L, 44L),
  Timestamp = structure(c(17897, 17928, 17957, 17988, 18018, 18048, 18079, 18109, 18169, 18200, 18230, 18233, 18262, 18302, 18323, 18353, 18383, 18414, 18444, 18475, 18535, 18566, 18596, 18599, 18628, 18660, 18713, 18744, 18770, 18799, 18827, 18856, 18884, 18913, 18944, 18628, 18660, 18713, 18744, 18770, 18799, 18827, 18856, 18884, 18913, 18944, 18262, 18302, 18323, 18353, 18383, 18414, 18444, 18475, 18535, 18566, 18596, 18599, 18628, 18660, 18713, 18744, 18770, 18799, 18827, 18856, 18884, 18913, 18944, 17897, 17928, 17957, 17988, 18018, 18048, 18079, 18109, 18169, 18200, 18230, 18233, 18262, 18302, 18323, 18353, 18383, 18414, 18444, 18475, 18535, 18566, 18596, 18599, 17897, 17928, 17957, 17988, 18018, 18048, 18079), class = "Date")
), row.names = c(5L, 10L, 15L, 20L, 25L, 30L, 35L, 40L, 45L, 50L, 55L, 60L, 61L, 66L, 71L, 76L, 81L, 86L, 91L, 96L, 101L, 106L, 111L, 116L, 122L, 127L, 132L, 137L, 142L, 147L, 152L, 157L, 162L, 167L, 172L, 124L, 129L, 134L, 139L, 144L, 149L, 154L, 159L, 164L, 169L, 174L, 62L, 67L, 72L, 77L, 82L, 87L, 92L, 97L, 102L, 107L, 112L, 117L, 125L, 130L, 135L, 140L, 145L, 150L, 155L, 160L, 165L, 170L, 175L, 3L, 8L, 13L, 18L, 23L, 28L, 33L, 38L, 43L, 48L, 53L, 58L, 63L, 68L, 73L, 78L, 83L, 88L, 93L, 98L, 103L, 108L, 113L, 118L, 1L, 6L, 11L, 16L, 21L, 26L, 31L), class = "data.frame")

ggplot(df, aes(x=Timestamp, y=Frequency, fill=Topic)) + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = '1 month', date_labels = "%b-%y")+
  geom_area(alpha=0.6 , size=1, colour="black", position = position_fill())+
  theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.box = "horizontal")+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 1)) +
  scale_fill_discrete(limits = paste("Topic", LETTERS[c(1,7,9,2,5,8,3,4,6)], sep = "_"))
```

[image]

In order to get a separate legend per year, you basically need to create separate plots with respective legends. The main challenge is to assign the correct color values and guide limits.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

## first get the colors
my_cols <- scales::hue_pal()(9)
## assign them to the order you like
names(my_cols) = paste("Topic", LETTERS[c(1,7,9,2,5,8,3,4,6)], sep = "_")

p_list <- 
  df %>%
  ## create year variable by which you split into a list
  mutate(year = lubridate::year(Timestamp)) %>%
  split(.$year) %>%
  ## pass this list to a loop function to create three separate plots 
  map(~ggplot(data = .x, aes(x=Timestamp, y=Frequency, fill=Topic)) + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = '1 month', date_labels = "%b-%y")+
  geom_area(alpha=0.6 , size=1, colour="black", position = position_fill())+
  theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.box = "horizontal")+
    ## changing label position because of crowding
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 1, label.position = "bottom")) +
  ## you will need to set the limits to the unique values in each plot
    ## I am also removing the guide title because of the visual crowding
  scale_fill_manual(NULL, values = my_cols, limits = unique(.x$Topic))
  
  )

## patchwork is great for such things
wrap_plots(p_list)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I think this is a great solution. One more question, is there any possibility that we can do something in a more programmable way rather than specifying order manually in ```scale_fill```?

Comment: @AneesBaqir The more specific you are about you color scheme, the more difficult automatisation will be. But you could do something like: get the unique topics per year and assign your colors to it. that can be pretty automatic

Comment: Yes, all the topics in each year are unique and color scheme doesn't matter. How would you recommend that I implement this approach?

Comment: @AneesBaqir for example, instead of the manual order assignment, when creating `my_cols`, use `names(my_cols) = unique(df$Topic)` instead